# HTML 5 header element ANDI accessibility issue, how to remove landmark capability

Tags: html, accessibility

I am using a html5 header element to display a logo inside the body. ANDI accessibiility compatibility is recognizing this as a landmark. I tried going thru the documentations but they only specifiy how to add landmark but do not mention how to ignore or remove an unwanted landmark.

How do I make header/any element in future a non landmark. Any attributes I could set or any directions would be helpful.
Note: I'd still like to be able to use header element.

If useful, its an angular application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `role` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Don't use a `<header>` element.

It isn't about what *you want* it is about what *people need* in order to access your site correctly.

Semantics are really important for accessibility, especially for screen reader users and trying to rely on `aria` to override an elements semantic role is a bad idea.

Screen reader users navigate by landmarks and expect to see them in certain places, this is one of the main reasons it is important.

There is nothing wrong with using `<divs>` for things that do not form part of the document structure.

**If you want to know what to use instead please add a fiddle / link to your question**, just in case there is a more appropriate element with the correct semantics.

### So if I need to do it for legitimate reasons.

Use `role="presentation"` as this converts an element to be treated like a `<div>` (which has no semantic role.). However as stated this should be used sparingly support for [`aria` is not as good as you might think.](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/).